# DataFrame: поиск индексов всех нулевых элементов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Я решаю задачу TSP (Travel Salesman Problem). В алгоритме предусмотрен цикл по обработке данных матрицы - поиск всех нулеых элементов и последовательная оценка каждого из этих элементов для принятия решения. Отсюда и взялся цикл. Для поиска вектора всех нулевых элементов я использую метод

```
result = np.where(df == 0)  # Найти все нулевые элементы - Numpy.
v_null = zip(result[0], result[1])  # Вектор, содержащий координаты нулевых элементов
```

Есть ли подобный метод в DataFrame, который выдает вектор индексов всех найденных по какому-то условию элементов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть, например:

```
In [85]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 5)), columns=list("abcde"))

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  2  3  2  3  1
1  4  3  3  1  4
2  4  2  2  2  3
3  0  4  3  2  3
4  4  2  0  0  0

In [87]: df[df.eq(0)].stack().reset_index()
Out[87]:
   level_0 level_1    0
0        3       a  0.0
1        4       c  0.0
2        4       d  0.0
3        4       e  0.0
```

Столбцы `level_0` и `level_1` - содержат индексы нулевых элементов.